# What is a build prefix?

Tags: build, terminology, conda, prefix

The term "build prefix" is used extensively in, for example, the [Conda documentation](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/build-packages/environment-variables.html#env-vars), but does not seem to be defined explicitly anywhere.

> **Question:** What is a build prefix in general? What is a build prefix in the context of Conda?

The $PREFIX environment variable is described as "the build prefix to which the build script should install". So it seems that build prefixes are related to installation locations and build scripts.

But the installation location of what specifically? A build script can do and install many things. Also, the word "prefix" seems to imply that a build prefix comes *before* (pre-) something. Before what?

In particular, it is unclear to me how one can distinguish $PREFIX, which is the "build prefix", and $CONDA_PREFIX, which is "The path to the conda environment used to build the package".

Comment: This thread explains what the build prefix is in general: https://askubuntu.com/questions/891835/what-does-prefix-do-exactly-when-used-in-configure

Comment: @DavidBrochart Thank you for the pointer!